# What are some of the more 'controversial' statements that are found in Moreh Nevuchim (Rambam)?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, authorship

and is it clear that he wrote it.

I'm simply curious.

Comment: The same Yaakov Emden who said that the Rashbi didn't write the Zohar says that the Rambam didn't write the  Moreh. But I don't think anyone else agrees

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The Yaavetz isn't the only one who says that the Zohar wasn't written by Rashbi.

Comment: What qualifies as 'controversial'? This same question can be applied to and should hopefully be addressed in any answer given. There may have been things he wrote then that were not normative Jewish thought but are now. Or vice versa. Or perhaps over the last almost thousand years different ideas of his were normative in certain communities at certain times but not in others. All of this still doesn't get into the fact that controversial implies controversy. Consider that something he said was not normative at that point in time and never was after that, but no controversy aroused out of it.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin When did he lose his Semicha?

Comment: This question would be not opinion-based if the reason behind it were statements according to anti maimonideans in his time.

Comment: Controversial according to whose standards?

Answer (score 9):

Below are a bunch of "controversial" statements from the Moreh Nevuchim. All quotes are from the Friedlander translation, with links to an online version of this translation.

Similar to the disclaimer in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/deviations-of-ralbag-from-normative-jewish-theology/88099#88099), not all controversial statements are equal. Some are very controversial, while others have other rishonim who agree with them. Because the question uses the vaguely defined term "controversial" I chose statements based on my own subjective opinion.

**[1:7](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp017.htm)**

> A man who has instructed another in any subject, and has improved his
>   knowledge, may in like manner be regarded as the parent of the person
>   taught, because he is the author of that knowledge: and thus the
>   pupils of the prophets are called "sons of the prophets," as I shall
>   explain when treating of the homonymity of ben (son). In this
>   figurative sense, the verb yalad (to bear) is employed when it is said
>   of Adam, "And Adam lived an hundred and thirty years, and begat
>   (va-yoled) a son in his own likeness, in his form" (Gen. V. 3). As
>   regards the words, "the form of Adam, and his likeness," we have
>   already stated (ch. i.) their meaning. Those sons of Adam who were
>   born before that time were not human in the true sense of the word,
>   they had not "the form of man." With reference to Seth who had been
>   instructed, enlightened and brought to human perfection, it could
>   rightly be said, "he (Adam) begat a son in his likeness, in his form."
>   It is acknowledged that a man who does not possess this "form" (the
>   nature of which has just been explained) is not human, but a mere
>   animal in human shape and form.

In this quote he seems to be saying that people who aren't brought to perfection are really just animals, and he apparently includes Cain and Abel among these.

---

[**1:36**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp046.htm)

> If you think that there is an excuse for those who believe in the
>   corporeality of God on the ground of their training, their ignorance
>   or their defective comprehension, you must make the same concession to
>   the worshippers of idols: their worship is due to ignorance, or to
>   early training, "they continue in the custom of their fathers." (TḄ.
>   Ḥullin, 13a) You will perhaps say that the literal interpretation of
>   the Bible causes men to fall into that doubt, but you must know that
>   idolaters were likewise brought to their belief by false imaginations
>   and ideas. There is no excuse whatever for those who, being unable to
>   think for themselves, do not accept [the doctrine of the
>   incorporeality of God] from the true philosophers. I do not consider
>   those men as infidels who are unable to prove the incorporeality, but
>   I hold those to be so Who do not believe it, especially when they see
>   that Onkelos and Jonathan avoid [in reference to God] expressions
>   implying corporeality as much as possible.

Here he seems to say that one is guilty of heresy even if it was unintentional.

---

[**1:42**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp052.htm)

> Mavet signifies "death" and "severe illness," as in "His heart died
>   (va-yamot) within him, and he became as a stone" (1 Sam. xxv. 37),
>   that is, his illness was severe. For this reason it is stated
>   concerning the son of the woman of Zarephath, "And his sickness was so
>   sore, that there was no breath left in him" (1 Kings xvii. 17). The
>   simple expression va-yamoth would have given the idea that he was very
>   ill, near death, like Nabal when he heard what had taken place.
>
> Some of the Andalusian authors say that his breath was suspended, so
>   that no breathing could be perceived at all, as sometimes an invalid
>   is seized with a fainting fit or an attack of asphyxia, and it cannot
>   be discovered whether he is alive or dead: in this condition the
>   patient may remain a day or two.

In this quote he appears to grant the possibility that the boy had never died, and therefore Eliyahu had not actually performed a resurrection of the dead.

---

**[1:61](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp071.htm)**

> You must beware of sharing the error of those who write amulets
>   (kameot). Whatever you hear from them, or read in their works,
>   especially in reference to the names which they form by combination,
>   is utterly senseless; they call these combinations shemot (names) and
>   believe that their pronunciation demands sanctification and
>   purification, and that by using them they are enabled to work
>   miracles. Rational persons ought not to listen to such men, nor in any
>   way believe their assertions.

**[1:62](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp072.htm)**

> How grievously has this passage been misunderstood! Many believe that
>   the forty-two letters are merely to be pronounced mechanically; that
>   by knowledge of these, without any further interpretation, they can
>   attain to these exalted ends, although it is stated that he who
>   desires to obtain a knowledge of that name must be trained in the
>   virtues named before, and go through all the great preparations which
>   are mentioned in that passage. On the contrary, it is evident that all
>   this preparation aims at a knowledge of Metaphysics, and includes
>   ideas which constitute the "secrets of the Law," as we have explained
>   (chap. xxxv.). In works on Metaphysics it has been shown that such
>   knowledge, i.e., the perception of the active intellect, can never be
>   forgotten: and this is meant by the phrase "his learning remaineth
>   with him."
>
> When bad and foolish men were reading such passages, they considered
>   them to be a support of their false pretensions and of their assertion
>   that they could, by means of an arbitrary combination of letters, form
>   a shem ("a name") which would act and operate miraculously when
>   written or spoken in a certain particular way. Such fictions,
>   originally invented by foolish men, were in the course of time
>   committed to writing, and came into the hands of good but weak-minded
>   and ignorant persons who were unable to discriminate between truth and
>   falsehood, and made a secret of these shemot (names). When after the
>   death of such persons those writings were discovered among their
>   papers, it was believed that they contained truths; for, "The simple
>   believeth every word" (Prov. xiv. 15).

In the above two quotes he rejects and ridicules parts of Mystical Judaism.

---

[**1:72**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp082.htm)

> The spherical bodies, on the other hand, have life, possess a soul by
>   which they move spontaneously; they have no properties by which they
>   could at any time come to a state of rest: in their perpetual
>   rotations they are not subject to any change, except that of position.
>   The question whether they are endowed with an intellect, enabling them
>   to comprehend, cannot be solved without deep research.

Here he argues that the celestial bodies are actually alive.

---

[**1:72**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp082.htm)

> Again, in the body of each individual there are parts which are
>   intended for a certain purpose, as the organs of nutrition for the
>   preservation of the individual, the organs of generation for the
>   preservation of the species, the hands and eyes for administering to
>   certain wants, as to food, etc.: there are also parts which, in
>   themselves, are not intended for any purpose, but are mere accessories
>   and adjuncts to the constitution of the other parts. The peculiar
>   constitution of the organs, indispensable for the conservation of
>   their particular forms and for the performance of their primary
>   functions, produces, whilst it serves its special purpose, according
>   to the nature of the substance, other things, such as the hair and the
>   complexion of the body. Being mere accessories, they are not formed
>   according to a fixed rule: some are altogether absent in many
>   individuals; and vary considerably in others. This is not the case
>   with the organs of the body. You never find that the liver of one
>   person is ten times larger than that of another person, but you may
>   find a person without a beard, or without hair on certain parts of his
>   body, or with a beard ten times longer than that of another man.
>   Instances of this phenomenon, viz., great variation as regards hair
>   and colour, are not rare. The same differences occur in the
>   constitution of the Universe. Some species exist as an integral part
>   of the whole system: these are constant and follow a fixed law; though
>   they vary as far as their nature permits, this variation is
>   insignificant in quantity and quality. Other species do not serve any
>   purpose: they are the mere result of the general nature of transient
>   things, as, e.g., the various insects which are generated in
>   dunghills, the animals generated in rotten fruit, or in fetid liquids,
>   and worms generated in the intestines, etc. In short, everything
>   devoid of the power of generation belongs to this class. You will,
>   therefore, find that these things do not follow a fixed law, although
>   their entire absence is just as impossible as the absence of different
>   complexions and of different kinds of hair amongst human beings.

In this quote he rejects God's total involvement in the world, saying that there are many things that simply exist for no purpose.

---

**[2:6](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp093.htm)**

> These passages do not convey the idea that God spoke, thought,
>   reflected, or that He consulted and employed the opinion of other
>   beings, as ignorant persons have believed. How could the Creator be
>   assisted by those whom He created! They only show that all parts of
>   the Universe, even the limbs of animals in their actual form, are
>   produced through angels: for natural forces and angels are identical.
>   How bad and injurious is the blindness of ignorance! Say to a person
>   who is believed to belong to the wise men of Israel that the Almighty
>   sends His angel to enter the womb of a woman and to form there the
>   fœtus, he will be satisfied with the account; he will believe it, and
>   even find in it a description of the greatness of God's might and
>   wisdom; although he believes that the angel consists of burning fire,
>   and is as big as a third part of the Universe, yet he considers it
>   possible as a divine miracle. But tell him that God gave the seed a
>   formative power which produces and shapes the limbs, and that this
>   power is called "angel," or that all forms are the result of the
>   influence of the Active Intellect, and that the latter is the angel,
>   the Prince of the world, frequently mentioned by our Sages, and he
>   will turn away; because he cannot comprehend the true greatness and
>   power of creating forces that act in a body without being perceived by
>   our senses. Our Sages have already stated--for him who has
>   understanding--that all forces that reside in a body are angels, much
>   more the forces that are active in the Universe. The theory that each
>   force acts only in one particular way, is expressed in Bereshit Rabba
>   (chap. 1.) as follows: "One angel does not perform two things, and two
>   angels do not perform one thing"; this is exactly the property of all
>   forces. We may find a confirmation of the opinion that the natural and
>   psychical forces of an individual are called angels in a statement of
>   our Sages which is frequently quoted, and occurs originally in
>   Bereshit Rabba (chap. lxxviii.): "Every day God creates a legion of
>   angels; they sing before Him, and disappear." When, in opposition to
>   this statement, other statements were quoted to the effect that angels
>   are eternal--and, in fact, it has repeatedly been shown that they live
>   permanently--the reply has been given that some angels live
>   permanently, others perish; and this is really the case; for
>   individual forces are transient, whilst the genera are permanent and
>   imperishable. Again, we read (in Bereshit Rabba, chap. lxxxv.), in
>   reference to the relation between Judah and Tamar: "R. Jochanan said
>   that Judah was about to pass by [without noticing Tamar], but God
>   caused the angel of lust, i.e., the libidinous disposition, to present
>   himself to him." Man's disposition is here called an angel. Likewise
>   we frequently meet with the phrase "the angel set over a certain
>   thing.'' In Midrash-Koheleth (on Eccles. x. 7) the following passage
>   occurs: "When man sleeps, his soul speaks to the angel, the angel to
>   the cherub." The intelligent reader will find here a clear statement
>   that man's imaginative faculty is also called "angel," and that
>   "cherub" is used for man's intellectual faculty. How beautiful must
>   this appear to him who understands it; how absurd to the ignorant!

Here he rejects and ridicules a standard conception of angels.

---

**[2:8](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp095.htm)**

> You must not find it strange that Aristotle differs here from the
>   opinion of our Sages. The theory of the music of the spheres is
>   connected with the theory of the motion of the stars in a fixed
>   sphere, and our Sages have, in this astronomical question, abandoned
>   their own theory in favour of the theory of others. Thus, it is
>   distinctly stated, "The wise men of other nations have defeated the
>   wise men of Israel." It is quite right that our Sages have abandoned
>   their own theory: for speculative matters every one treats according
>   to the results of his own study, and every one accepts that which
>   appears to him established by proof.

In this quote he asserts that the Sages were mistaken in scientific matters. In [3:14](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp150.htm) he again mentions their scientific mistakes.

---

**[2:11](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp098.htm)**

> All we wish to point out is this: in the first place, that the whole
>   Creation is divided into three parts, viz. (1) the pure Intelligences;
>   (2) the bodies of the spheres endowed with permanent forms--(the forms
>   of these bodies do not pass from one substratum to another, nor do
>   their substrata undergo any change whatever); and (3) the transient
>   earthly beings, all of which consist of the same substance.
>   Furthermore, we desire to show that the ruling power emanates from the
>   Creator, and is received by the Intelligences according to their
>   order: from the Intelligences part of the good and the light bestowed
>   upon them is communicated to the spheres, and the latter, being in
>   possession of the abundance obtained of the Intelligences, transmit
>   forces and properties unto the beings of this transient world. We
>   must, however, add that the part which benefits the part below it in
>   the order described does not exist for the sole purpose of producing
>   that benefit. For if this were the case it would lead to the paradox
>   that the higher, better, and nobler beings existed for the sake of
>   beings lower in rank, whilst in reality the object should be of
>   greater importance than the means applied for attaining it. No
>   intelligent person will admit that this is possible.

Here he indicates that the celestial bodies are greater than man, and therefore it cannot be that everything was created for the sake of man. (He reiterates this in [3:12](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp148.htm).)

---

**[2:16](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp103.htm)**

> IN this chapter I will first expound my view on this question, and
>   then support it by argument-not by such arguments as those of the
>   Mutakallemim, who believe that they have proved the Creatio ex nihilo.
>   I will not deceive myself, and consider dialectical methods as proofs;
>   and the fact that a certain proposition has been proved by a
>   dialectical argument win never induce me to accept that proposition,
>   but, on the contrary, will weaken my faith in it, and cause me to
>   doubt it. For when we understand the fallacy of a proof, our faith in
>   the proposition itself is shaken. It is therefore better that a
>   proposition which cannot be demonstrated be received as an axiom, or
>   that one of the two opposite solutions of the problem be accepted on
>   authority. The methods by which the Mutakallemim proved the Creatio ex
>   nihilo have already been described by me, and I have exposed their
>   weak points. As to the proofs of Aristotle and his followers for the
>   Eternity of the Universe, they are, according to my opinion, not
>   conclusive; they are open to strong objections, as will be explained.
>   I intend to show that the theory of the Creation, as taught in
>   Scripture, contains nothing that is impossible; and that all those
>   philosophical arguments which seem to disprove our view contain weak
>   points which make them inconclusive, and render the attacks on our
>   view untenable. Since I am convinced of the correctness of my method,
>   and consider either of the two theories--viz., the Eternity of the
>   Universe, and the Creation--as admissible, I accept the latter on the
>   authority of Prophecy, which can teach things beyond the reach of
>   philosophical speculation. For the belief in prophecy is, as will be
>   shown in the course of this treatise, consistent even with the belief
>   in the Eternity of the Universe. When I have established the
>   admissibility of our theory, I will, by philosophical reasoning, show
>   that our theory of the Creation is more acceptable than that of the
>   Eternity of the Universe; and although our theory includes points open
>   to criticism, I will show that there are much stronger reasons for the
>   rejection of the theory of our opponents.

In this quote he states that (contrary to several rishonim who claim to have done so) it is impossible to prove that the universe was created, and we have to accept it on faith.

---

**[2:25](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp112.htm)**

> WE do not reject the Eternity of the Universe, because certain
>   passages in Scripture confirm the Creation; for such passages are not
>   more numerous than those in which God is represented as a corporeal
>   being; nor is it impossible or difficult to find for them a suitable
>   interpretation. We might have explained them in the same manner as we
>   did in respect to the Incorporeality of God. We should perhaps have
>   had an easier task in showing that the Scriptural passages referred to
>   are in harmony with the theory of the Eternity of the Universe if we
>   accepted the latter, than we had in explaining the anthropomorphisms
>   in the Bible when we rejected the idea that God is corporeal. For two
>   reasons, however, we have not done so, and have not accepted the
>   Eternity of the Universe. First, the Incorporeality of God has been
>   demonstrated by proof: those passages in the Bible, which in their
>   literal sense contain statements that can be refuted by proof, must
>   and can be interpreted otherwise. But the Eternity of the Universe has
>   not been proved; a mere argument in favour of a certain theory is not
>   sufficient reason for rejecting the literal meaning of a Biblical
>   text, and explaining it figuratively, when the opposite theory can be
>   supported by an equally good argument.
>
> Secondly, our belief in the Incorporeality of God is not contrary to
>   any of the fundamental principles of our religion: it is not contrary
>   to the words of any prophet. Only ignorant people believe that it is
>   contrary to the teaching of Scripture: but we have shown that this is
>   not the case: on the contrary, Scripture teaches the Incorporeality of
>   God. If we were to accept the Eternity of the Universe as taught by
>   Aristotle, that everything in the Universe is the result of fixed
>   laws, that Nature does not change, and that there is nothing
>   supernatural, we should necessarily be in opposition to the foundation
>   of our religion, we should disbelieve all miracles and signs, and
>   certainly reject all hopes and fears derived from Scripture, unless
>   the miracles are also explained figuratively. The Allegorists amongst
>   the Mohammedans have done this, and have thereby arrived at absurd
>   conclusions. If, however, we accepted the Eternity of the Universe in
>   accordance with the second of the theories which we have expounded
>   above (ch. xxiii.), and assumed, with Plato, that the heavens are
>   likewise transient, we should not be in opposition to the fundamental
>   principles of our religion; this theory would not imply the rejection
>   of miracles, but, on the contrary, would admit them as possible. The
>   Scriptural text might have been explained accordingly, and many
>   expressions might have been found in the Bible and in other writings
>   that would confirm and support this theory. But there is no necessity
>   for this expedient, so long as the theory has not been proved. As
>   there is no proof sufficient to convince us, this theory need not be
>   taken into consideration, nor the other one; we take the text of the
>   Bible literally, and say that it teaches us a truth which we cannot
>   prove; and the miracles are evidence for the correctness of our view.

Here he says that the text of the Torah itself does not even necessarily imply that the universe was created.

---

**[2:29](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp116.htm)**

> Our opinion, in support of which we have quoted these passages, is
>   clearly established, namely, that no prophet or sage has ever
>   announced the destruction of the Universe, or a change of its present
>   condition, or a permanent change of any of its properties. When our
>   Sages say, "The world remains six thousand years, and one thousand
>   years it will be waste," they do not mean a complete cessation of
>   existing things; the phrase "one thousand years it will be waste"
>   distinctly shows that time will continue: besides, this is the
>   individual opinion of one Rabbi, and in accordance with one particular
>   theory. But on the other hand the words, "There is nothing new under
>   the sun" (Eccles. i. 9), in the sense that no new creation takes place
>   in any way and under any circumstances, express the general opinion of
>   our Sages, and include a principle which every one of the doctors of
>   the Mishnah and the Talmud recognises and makes use of in his
>   arguments.

Here he rejects the Talmudic belief that the world will come to an end after a certain amount of time.

---

**[2:29](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp116.htm)**

> First, the account given in Scripture of the Creation is not, as is
>   generally believed, intended to be in all its parts literal.

In this quote he argues that the creation narrative in Genesis is not necessarily literally an accurate description of the creation of the universe.

---

**[2:34](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp121.htm)**

> Here a principle is laid clown which I have constantly expounded,
>   viz., that all prophets except Moses receive the prophecy through an
>   angel. Note it.

Here he states that no other prophets received communications directly from God.

---

**[2:36](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp123.htm)**

> On the contrary, the multitude must be considered according to their
>   true worth; some of them are undoubtedly like domesticated cattle, and
>   others like wild beasts, and these only engage the mind of the perfect
>   and distinguished man in so far as he desires to guard himself from
>   injury, in case of contact with them, and to derive some benefit from
>   them when necessary.

Here he affirms that many people are really just animals, due to having not intellectually perfected themselves.

---

**[2:39](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp126.htm)**

> It is clear that the Law is normal in this sense; for it contains
>   "Just statutes and judgments" (Deut. iv. 8); but "just" is here
>   identical with "equibalanced." The statutes of the Law do not impose
>   burdens or excesses as are implied in the service of a hermit or
>   pilgrim, and the like; but, on the other hand, they are not so
>   deficient as to lead to gluttony or lewdness, or to prevent, as the
>   religious laws of the heathen nations do, the development of man's
>   moral and intellectual faculties. We intend to discuss in this treatise the reasons of the commandments, and we shall then show, as far as necessary, the justice and wisdom of the Law, on account of which it is said: "The Law of God is perfect, refreshing the heart" (Ps. xix. 8). There are persons who believe that the Law commands much exertion and great pain, but due consideration will show them their error. Later on I will show how easy it is for the perfect to obey the Law.

Here he rejects a common view that the Torah is meant to be difficult.

---

**[2:41](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp128.htm)**

> You must know that whenever Scripture relates that the Lord or an
>   angel spoke to a person, this took place in a dream or in a prophetic
>   vision.

Here he states that any Scriptural event involving an angel did not actually occur as described, but simply occurred in the person's head. In [Chapter 42](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp129.htm) he mentions some famous examples, such as the angels appearing to Avraham, the wrestling match with Yaakov, and the incident with Billam and the talking donkey.

---

**[2:47](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp134.htm)**

> What Scripture says about Og, "Behold, his bedstead was an iron
>   bedstead, nine cubits its length," etc. (Deut.), does not belong to
>   this class of figures, for the bedstead (eres, comp. arsenu, Song of
>   Sol. i. 16) is never exactly, of the same dimensions as the person
>   using it; it is not like a dress that fits round the body; it is
>   always greater than the person that sleeps therein; as a rule, is it
>   by a third longer. If, therefore, the bed of Og was nine cubits in
>   length, he must, according to this proportion, have been six cubits
>   high, or a little more. The words, "by the cubit of a man," mean, by
>   the measure of an ordinary man, and not by the measure of Og; for men
>   have the limbs in a certain proportion. Scripture thus tells us that
>   Og was double as long as an ordinary person, or a little less. This is
>   undoubtedly an exceptional height among men, but not quite impossible.

In this quote he rejects the Talmudic interpretation of Og's size.

---

**[3:15](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp151.htm)**

> THAT which is impossible has a permanent and constant property, which
>   is not the result of some agent, and cannot in any way change, and
>   consequently we do not ascribe to God the power of doing what is
>   impossible. No thinking man denies the truth of this maxim; none
>   ignore it, but such as have no idea of Logic. There is, however, a
>   difference of opinion among philosophers with reference to the
>   existence of any particular thing. Some of them consider its existence
>   to be impossible, and hold that God cannot produce the thing in
>   question, whilst others think that it is possible, and that God can
>   create it if He pleases to do so. E.g., all philosophers consider that
>   it is impossible for one substratum to have at the same moment two
>   opposite properties, or for the elementary components of a thing,
>   substance and accident, to interchange, so that the substance becomes
>   accident, and the accident becomes substance, or for a material
>   substance to be without accident. Likewise it is impossible that God
>   should produce a being like Himself, or annihilate, corporify, or
>   change Himself. The power of God is not assumed to extend to any of
>   these Impossibilities.

Here he limits God's abilities.

---

There is apparently a character limit for answers, which I have exceeded, so this answer will be continued in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92974/13438).

Comment: another great answer :)

Comment: IIRC he also says in Mishneh Torah/Yad Hachazaka that the celestial bodies have intellect, I think its hilchos deios.

Answer (score 6):

Continuation of [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92973/13438):

**[3:17](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp153.htm)**

> We, however, believe that all these human affairs are managed with
>   justice; far be it from God to do wrong, to punish any one unless the
>   punishment is necessary and merited. It is distinctly stated in the
>   Law, that all is done in accordance with justice; and the words of our
>   Sages generally express the same idea. They clearly say: "There is no
>   death without sin, no sufferings without transgression." (B. T.
>   Shabbath, 55a.) Again, "The deserts of an are meted out to him in the
>   same measure which he himself employs." (Mish. Sotah, i. 7.) These are
>   the words of the Mishnah. Our Sages declare it wherever opportunity is
>   given, that the idea of God necessarily implies justice; that He will
>   reward the most pious for all their pure and upright actions, although
>   no direct commandment was given them through a prophet; and that He
>   will punish all the evil deeds of men, although they have not been
>   prohibited by a prophet, if common sense warns against them, as e.g.,
>   injustice and violence. Thus our Sages say: "God does not deprive any
>   being of the full reward [of its good deed]" (B. T. Pes. 118a) again,
>   "He who says that God remits part of a punishment;, will be punished
>   severely; He is long-suffering, but is sure to exact payment." (B. T.
>   Baba K. 50a.) Another saying is this: "He who has received a
>   commandment and acts accordingly is not like him who acts in the same
>   manner without being commanded to do so" (B. T. Kidd. 31a); and it is
>   distinctly added that he who does a good thing without being
>   commanded, receives nevertheless his reward. The same principle is
>   expressed in all sayings of our Sages. But they contain an additional
>   doctrine which is not found in the Law; viz., the doctrine of
>   "afflictions of love," as taught by some of our Sages. According to
>   this doctrine it is possible that a person be afflicted without having
>   previously committed any sin, in order that his future reward may be
>   increased; a view which is held by the Mu’tazilites, but is not
>   supported by any Scriptural text.

Here he bases normative Jewish thought on a rejected Talmudic passage, and he rejects another unrejected Talmudic passage.

---

**[3:17](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp153.htm)**

> My opinion on this principle of Divine Providence I will now explain
>   to you. In the principle which I now proceed to expound I do not rely
>   on demonstrative proof, but on my conception of the spirit of the
>   Divine Law, and the writings of the Prophets. The principle which I
>   accept is far less open to objections, and is more reasonable than the
>   opinions mentioned before. It is this: In the lower or sublunary
>   portion of the Universe Divine Providence does not extend to the
>   individual members of species except in the case of mankind. It is
>   only in this species that the incidents in the existence of the
>   individual beings, their good and evil fortunes, are the result of
>   justice, in accordance with the words, "For all His ways are
>   judgment." But I agree with Aristotle as regards all other living
>   beings, and à fortiori as regards plants and all the rest of earthly
>   creatures. For I do not believe that it is through the interference of
>   Divine Providence that a certain leaf drops [from a tree], nor do I
>   hold that when a certain spider catches a certain fly, that this is
>   the direct result of a special decree and will of God in that moment;
>   it is not by a particular Divine decree that the spittle of a certain
>   person moved, fell on a certain gnat in a certain place, and killed
>   it; nor is it by the direct will of God that a certain fish catches
>   and swallows a certain worm on the surface of the water. In all these
>   cases the action is, according to my opinion, entirely due to chance,
>   as taught by Aristotle. Divine Providence is connected with Divine
>   intellectual influence, and the same beings which are benefited by the
>   latter so as to become intellectual, and to comprehend things
>   comprehensible to rational beings, are also under the control of
>   Divine Providence, which examines all their deeds in order to reward
>   or punish them. It may be by mere chance that a ship goes down with
>   all her contents, as in the above-mentioned instance, or the roof of a
>   house falls upon those within; but it is not due to chance, according
>   to our view, that in the one instance the men went into the ship, or
>   remained in the house in the other instance: it is due to the will of
>   God, and is in accordance with the justice of His judgments, the
>   method of which our mind is incapable of understanding.

Here he argues that much of the world is not governed by divine providence.

---

[**3:18**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp154.htm)

> The relation of Divine Providence is therefore not the same to all
>   men; the greater the human perfection a person has attained, the
>   greater the benefit he derives from Divine Providence. This benefit is
>   very great in the case of prophets, and varies according to the degree
>   of their prophetic faculty: as it varies in the case of pious and good
>   men according to their piety and uprightness. For it is the intensity
>   of the Divine intellectual influence that has inspired the prophets,
>   guided the good in their actions, and perfected the wisdom of the
>   pious. In the same proportion as ignorant and disobedient persons are
>   deficient in that Divine influence, their condition is inferior, and
>   their rank equal to that of irrational beings: and they are "like unto
>   the beasts" (Ps. xlix. 21). For this reason it was not only considered
>   a light thing to slay them, but it was even directly commanded for the
>   benefit of mankind. This belief that God provides for every individual
>   human being in accordance with his merits is one of the fundamental
>   principles on which the Law is founded.

In this quote he says that even for man Divine providence is limited, and he states that the ignorant are little more than animals and their lives are not very valuable.

---

[3:22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp158.htm)

> I believe that I have fully explained the idea contained in the
>   account of Job; but I will now show the character of the opinion
>   attributed to Job, and of the opinions attributed to his friends, and
>   support my statement by proofs gathered from the words of each of
>   them. We need not take notice of the remaining passages which are only
>   required for the context, as has been explained to you in the
>   beginning of this treatise.

Here he states that large swaths of Scripture have no inherent meaning/value/purpose, and simply exist to provide context for the important parts.

---

**[3:26](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp162.htm)**

> I will now tell you what intelligent persons ought to believe in this
>   respect; namely, that each commandment has necessarily a cause, as far
>   as its general character is concerned, and serves a certain object;
>   but as regards its details we hold that it has no ulterior object.
>   Thus killing animals for the purpose of obtaining good food is
>   certainly useful, as we intend to show (below, ch. xlviii.); that,
>   however, the killing should not be performed by neḥirah (poleaxing the
>   animal), but by sheḥitah (cutting the neck), and by dividing the
>   œsophagus and the windpipe in a certain place; these regulations and
>   the like are nothing but tests for man's obedience. In this sense you
>   will understand the example quoted by our Sages [that there is no
>   difference] between killing the animal by cutting its neck in front
>   and cutting it in the back. I give this instance only because it has
>   been mentioned by our Sages; but in reality [there is some reason for
>   these regulations]. For as it has become necessary to eat the flesh of
>   animals, it was intended by the above regulations to ensure an easy
>   death and to effect it by suitable means; whilst decapitation requires
>   a sword or a similar instrument, the sheḥitah can be performed with
>   any instrument; and in order to ensure an easy death our Sages
>   insisted that the knife should be well sharpened.
>
> A more suitable instance can be cited from the detailed commandments
>   concerning sacrifices. The law that sacrifices should be brought is
>   evidently of great use, as will be shown by us (infra, chap. xlvi.);
>   but we cannot say why one offering should be a lamb, whilst another is
>   a ram; and why a fixed number of them should be brought. Those who
>   trouble themselves to find a cause for any of these detailed rules,
>   are in my eyes void of sense: they do not remove any difficulties, but
>   rather increase them. Those who believe that these detailed rules
>   originate in a certain cause, are as far from the truth as those who
>   assume that the whole law is useless. You must know that Divine Wisdom
>   demanded it--or, if you prefer, say that circumstances made it
>   necessary--that there should be parts [of His work] which have no
>   certain object: and as regards the Law, it appears to be impossible
>   that it should not include some matter of this kind. That it cannot be
>   avoided may be seen from the following instance. You ask why must a
>   lamb be sacrificed and not a ram? but the same question would be
>   asked, why a ram had been commanded instead of a lamb, so long as one
>   particular kind is required. The same is to be said as to the question
>   why were seven lambs sacrificed and not eight; the same question might
>   have been asked if there were eight, ten, or twenty lambs, so long as
>   some definite number of lambs were sacrificed. It is almost similar to
>   the nature of a thing which can receive different forms, but actually
>   receives one of them. We must not ask why it has this form and not
>   another which is likewise possible, because we should have to ask the
>   same question if instead of its actual form the thing had any of the
>   other possible forms. Note this, and understand it. The repeated
>   assertion of our Sages that there are reasons for all commandments,
>   and the tradition that Solomon knew them, refer to the general purpose
>   of the commandments, and not to the object of every detail.

In this quote he asserts that the details of mitzvos have no reasons/purpose.

---

**[3:32](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp168.htm)**

> But the custom which was in those days general among all men, and the
>   general mode of worship in which the Israelites were brought up,
>   consisted in sacrificing animals in those temples which contained
>   certain images, to bow down to those images, and to bum incense before
>   them; religious and ascetic persons were in those days the persons
>   that were devoted to the service in the temples erected to the stars,
>   as has been explained by us. It was in accordance with the wisdom and
>   plan of God, as displayed in the whole Creation, that He did not
>   command us to give up and to discontinue all these manners of service;
>   for to obey such a commandment it would have been contrary to the
>   nature of man, who generally cleaves to that to which he is used; it
>   would in those days have made the same impression as a prophet would
>   make at present if he called us to the service of God and told us in
>   His name, that we should not pray to Him, not fast, not seek His help
>   in time of trouble; that we should serve Him in thought, and not by
>   any action. For this reason God allowed these kinds of service to
>   continue; He transferred to His service that which had formerly served
>   as a worship of created beings, and of things imaginary and unreal,
>   and commanded us to serve Him in the same manner; viz., to build unto
>   Him a temple; comp. "And they shall make unto me a sanctuary" (Exod.
>   xxv. 8); to have the altar erected to His name; comp. "An altar of
>   earth thou shalt make unto me" (ibid. xx. 21); to offer the sacrifices
>   to Him; comp. "If any man of you bring an offering unto the Lord"
>   (Lev. i. 2), to bow down to Him and to bum incense before Him. He has
>   forbidden to do any of these things to any other being; comp. "He who
>   sacrificeth unto any God, save the Lord only, he shall be utterly
>   destroyed" (Exod. xxii. 19); "For thou shalt bow down to no other God"
>   (ibid. xxxiv. 14). He selected priests for the service in the temple;
>   comp. "And they shall minister unto me in the priest's office" (ibid.
>   xxviii. 41). He made it obligatory that certain gifts, called the
>   gifts of the Levites and the priests, should be assigned to them for
>   their maintenance while they are engaged in the service of the temple
>   and its sacrifices. By this Divine plan it was effected that the
>   traces of idolatry were blotted out, and the truly great principle of
>   our faith, the Existence and Unity of God, was firmly established;
>   this result was thus obtained without deterring or confusing the minds
>   of the people by the abolition of the service to which they were
>   accustomed and which alone was familiar to them.

Here he claims that sacrifices (which form a large portion of the Torah) are just a necessary evil, catering to the unsophisticated level of understanding God that the ancients had.

---

**[3:45](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp181.htm)**

> The commandment that the stones of the altar shall not be hewn and
>   that no iron tool shall be lifted up upon them (Deut. xxvii. 5), has
>   been explained by our Sages as follows: It is not right that the tool
>   that shortens man's life should be lifted up upon that which gives
>   length of life. As an Agadic explanation this is good: but the real
>   reason is this: the heathen used to build their altars with hewn
>   stones: we ought not to imitate them.

Here he asserts that the Sages' explanation for the mitzvah is not the real explanation.

---

[**3:48**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp184.htm)

> When in the Talmud (Ber. p. 33b) those are blamed who use in their
>   prayer the phrase, "Thy mercy extendeth to young birds," it is the
>   expression of the one of the two opinions mentioned by us, namely,
>   that the precepts of the Law have no other reason but the Divine will.
>   We follow the other opinion.

Here he argues that a Talmudic law is based on a fundamentally incorrect philosophical notion.

---

**[3:51](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp187.htm)**

> Those who arrive at the palace, but go round about it, are those who
>   devote themselves exclusively to the study of the practical law; they
>   believe traditionally in true principles of faith, and learn the
>   practical worship of God, but are not trained in philosophical
>   treatment of the principles of the Law, and do not endeavour to
>   establish the truth of their faith by proof. Those who undertake to
>   investigate the principles of religion, have come into the
>   ante-chamber; and there is no doubt that these can also be divided
>   into different grades. But those who have succeeded in finding a proof
>   for everything that can be proved, who have a true knowledge of God,
>   so far as a true knowledge can be attained, and are near the truth,
>   wherever an approach to the truth is possible, they have reached the
>   goal, and are in the palace in which the king lives.
>
> My son, so long as you are engaged in studying the Mathematical
>   Sciences and Logic, you belong to those who go round about the palace
>   in search of the gate. Thus our Sages figuratively use the phrase:
>   "Ben-zoma is still outside." When you understand Physics, you have
>   entered the hall; and when, after completing the study of Natural
>   Philosophy, you master Metaphysics, you have entered the innermost
>   court, and are with the king in the same palace. You have attained the
>   degree of the wise men, who include men of different grades of
>   perfection.

Here he implies that those who devote themselves fully to the study of halacha are inferior to those who study advanced science and philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

> *“It is hard for a woman with whom an uncircumcised man has had sexual intercourse to separate from him. In my opinion this is the strongest of the reasons for circumcision.”*
>
> — Moses Maimonides (Rambam), *[The Guide for the Perplexed](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp185.htm)* (Moreh Nevuchim), M. Friedlânder translation (1904), Part III, Chapter 49, p. 609, 1190.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Andre and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: That's a quote from Midrash Rabbah. Is it the "strongest reasons for circumcision" that is controversial? It is brought as a reason by more than just him

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @RabbiKaii. Indeed he himself says "The Sages ... have stated this." Do you happen to know what Sages he's referring to? I find it controversial—more like contradictory, tbh—as it seems to contradict the precept that Jewish men and women should marry one another and stay married. Is that contradiction meant to indicate a hidden meaning, a covert condemnation of circumcision, which would indeed be controversial, and very much so?

Comment: @AndréLevy I can't look anything up now but I will try later. It is Bereshit Rabba 80, if you can look that up, and can see the commentaries on it. Sefaria also helps you find the places where it is quoted and in all that you'll find one theme discussed. Hashem calibrated the souls of people so that they should have the right amount of sex drive that it bonds them but doesn't interfere with (and rather enhances) the spiritual side of their marriage. Successful marriage and intimacy is the loftiest thing in all of Torah! Women are the bulwark of keeping it spiritual and holy. There's so much...

Comment: ...to discuss that I recommend you to go and study the topic of holy intimacy if you are of the right frame of mind and place in life. Either way it's clear to me, having studied this deeply, that the Chachamim are cognisant and wise, and don't see sexual addiction as a super glue to marriage, but rather a great danger to the really precious that is strived for in Holy Torah Matrimony

Comment: Right, found it: Rav Huna in Bereshit Rabba 80:11. And Rabbi Chunia on B'shit 34:26. And Kli Tamar on B'shit 3:16. Now, your assertion that *Hashem calibrated the souls of people so that they should have the right amount of sex drive that it bonds them but doesn't interfere with (and rather enhances) the spiritual side of their marriage* directly contradicts the 1st reason Rambam gives for circumcision: that *this commandment has not been prescribed with a view to perfecting what is defective congenitally, but to perfecting what is defective morally.*

Comment: This implies that HaShem did, in fact, *not* calibrate our sex drive all that well, that unless we circumcise we may fall prey to nymphomania, and that we need to interfere in His creation to "perfect it." This is such an outlandish assertion, especially from the Rambam, that I'm led to conclude that he is in fact saying the opposite in between his lines.

Comment: @AndréLevy the Rambam was unique in that he didn't seem to support the notion that we are defective congenitally, but supports that we are defective morally, as you said, and this is a process that helps us achieve the _correct_ moral balance in this area