# Why was the purpose of the creation of Man so dull?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, parashat-bereishit, creation

On the 6th day of the Creation, G-d consults angels (see [my other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100456/lets-make-the-man-isnt-the-man-the-purpose-of-the-creation)) and presents them with what *looks like* His vision of Man's goal on Earth:

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹקים נַעֲשֶׂה אָדָם בְּצַלְמֵנוּ כִּדְמוּתֵנוּ
> **וְיִרְדּוּ בִדְגַת הַיָּם וּבְעוֹף הַשָּׁמַיִם וּבַבְּהֵמָה וּבְכָל־הָאָרֶץ וּבְכָל־הָרֶמֶשׂ הָרֹמֵשׂ עַל־הָאָרֶץ׃**

> And God said, “Let us make man in our image, after our likeness. **For [and] they shall rule the fish of the sea, the birds of the sky, the cattle, the whole earth, and all the creeping things that creep on earth**.” [Genesis.1.26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.26?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

(In my understanding of the phrase, "and" presents the goal of an act, like in "let's build a house and we can live in it" - live in the house is the goal of building it, "let's have kids and they will take care of us" - taking care is the purpose of having kids.)

I would expect God to reveal something far nobler, like "and he will bring this world to perfection" or "and he will serve Me devotedly and make a dwelling for me on Earth".

Why was the presented purpose of man's creation so "dull"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lonely_Man_of_Faith

Comment: The נעשה אדם בצלמנו would imply a higher purpose. I think it's wrong to focus on "and they'll (incidentally) be ruling over the animals" etc.

Comment: @bondonk That answers on "what Man will we create" but not "what for", after all we don't share the same purpose with angels.

Comment: @AlBerko point taken. But it doesn't say 'purpose', it says צלמנו ודמותנו. That's not the same.

Comment: Why would your understanding of modern Hebrew have any impact on the Bible?

Comment: @wfb point taken, corrected

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the answer lies in challenging the initial assumption.
The OP writes:

> G-d consults angels...and presents them with what looks like His
> vision of Man's goal on Earth

Where do you see that he is presenting a vision of Man's goal in life with the latter part of the sentence?

I think that if G-d is presenting such a vision, it is with the first part of the sentence:

> וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֔ים נַֽעֲשֶׂ֥ה אָדָ֛ם בְּצַלְמֵ֖נוּ כִּדְמוּתֵ֑נוּ

G-d is creating a being in His image and likeness. Avoiding the exact question of what that means (a much broader discussion), it clearly is extending some sort of greatness and  "Godliness" to mankind.
In fact, Rav Hirsch comments that the name אדם "Adam" comes from the term הדום, a footstool. Mankind is created to be the footstool of Hashem, a resting place for Him in this world. Man's purpose is to make this world a G-dly world.

Put this way, the entire first part of the sentence is in fact expressing G-d's vision for mankind.

So what is the function of the rest of the verse? G-d is establishing a hierarchy among the creation. The pinnacle of all creation will be Man, who will rule over everything which came before it. Rav Hirsch points out that the whole world supports mankind, who in turn "supports" G-d in this world. (He says that the word אדמה, land, really means לאדם, for Man, since a ה at the end of a word can equal a ל at the beginning.)

(This fits well with [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he)'s comment:

> וירדו בדגת הים. יֵשׁ בַּלָּשׁוֹן הַזֶּה לְשׁוֹן רִדּוּי וּלְשׁוֹן
> יְרִידָה; זָכָה, רוֹדֶה בַחַיּוֹת וּבַבְּהֵמוֹת, לֹא זָכָה, נַעֲשֶׂה
> יָרוּד לִפְנֵיהֶם וְהַחַיָּה מוֹשֶׁלֶת בּוֹ

The term וירדו can imply either dominance or descendance. If Mankind merits it, we will dominate over the rest of creation. That means that we will be able to utilize everything to the fullest extent, to help us accomplish our role of being the Divine footstools. The second part of the verse will come true when we are living up to the first part.

If we don't live up to our task, then we will be subdued and controlled by the animals. We  won't merit to be Divine footstools, so we won't be able to control and utilize the world either.

According to this, the verse reads very precisely.

Comment: What was the downvoter for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed something somewhere. You said:

> I would expect God to reveal something far nobler, like "and he will
> bring this world to perfection" or "and he will serve Me devotedly and
> make a dwelling for me on Earth".

My response is that God said exactly that, but not in as straightforward a way. This is how I read the verse:

*Let us make man in our image* - the image of God, holy, benevolent, loving to all creatures/creations, just, a leader worthy of praise and full of compassion.

*And they shall rule the fish of the sea, the birds of the sky, the cattle, the whole earth, and all the creeping things that creep on earth.* - and they (humans) shall rule my creations like I would, for in My image was man made, and they shall rule the animals like I would: Through holiness, benevolence, loving to all, just, and a leader worthy of praise. Just like God would never cheat, murder, eat, steal, abuse, lie to, manipulate any of his creations, He expected the same from us. I don't know if it would be a perfect utopia, but it would certainly be closer to a utopia than what we have now.

And just like creating a utopia seems like an impossibly high bar, it seems to me God's expectations of us were no less lofty. Imagine how difficult it would be to rule the world as a reflection/emissary of God's image on earth. We didn't even make it to Chapter 3 before we failed. We failed because we allowed ourselves to be tempted by one of our citizens (the serpent), we failed because instead of admitting our mistakes and trying to set things right like a holy and just leader, we fled and hid in a cave hoping our mistakes would never come to light. We failed because we accepted no responsibility even when confronted by our creator. We failed because within a few generations we were murdering our brothers and eating our citizens that were entrusted to us by God Himself.

It seems to me that when one reads the verses the way I've shown that the point of Maimonides becomes more clear.

**Guide, III, 13, p. 452**

> It should not be believed that all things exist for the sake of the
> existence of man. On the contrary, all ***other beings*** too have been
> intended for their own sakes and not for the sake of something else.

All ***other beings*** were created for their own sake, but not mankind. Because God didn't need to create man, God could have ruled the earth on His own. But He decided to create man and entrust the responsibility of Earth and all life within it to us. God created everything else for its own sake, but He created us with a responsibility. And until we recognize that the Earth isn't here for our sake, but rather that we are here for the Earth's sake, things will only get worse.

Comment: Thank you. 1. I think you repeat Binyomin's answer, presenting "in our image" as a goal of its own. I don't see any support of your claim in Judaism, IMHO Adam was not created to be god and rule the Earth. 2, Where did you learn "*the image of God, holy, benevolent, loving to all creatures/creations, just, a leader worthy of praise and full of compassion.*" from? I don't see it in the text.

Comment: @AlBerko Adam was not created to be god and rule the earth and I never said so. Rather Adam was supposed to be like Noah, steward of life, who shared the food that the animals ate like God commanded Adam in the garden. Unfortunately we see Noah fall from his place of righteousness within a few chapters of the flood. A global wiping out of life was probably too much for him to handle.

Answer (score -1):

Taking your question as a given, I'd suggest that וירדו, the "ruling", is the second part of the process. The assertion that man will "rule" over the earth is not simply a description of what man will occasionally do. It is a declaration of man's very essence - man is **never** passively shaped by his environment, he **always** has an active role to play in the interaction.

And since every action we do, every choice we make, affects who we are and who we will become - why then, through this relationship of "ruling", we are continually developing ourselves - continuing the "making" that G-d began in the first part of the verse. Think of the famous mussar vort, where G-d says "let US make man", because man is a partner to his own "making", through his actions (עשייה being more of a "refining", as opposed to בריאה creating and יצירה forming).

It should also be noted that נעשה can just as easily be translated as a prediction and ירדו can just as easily be translated as a command. So it naturally flows from there that נעשה and ירדו are just two stages of a single process.

Comment: To interpret the verse I suggest you address the whole of it. it says "rule the fish of the sea, the birds of the sky, the cattle, the whole earth, and all the creeping things that creep on earth" How does your answer deal with those details? Unless you have a metaphorical interpretation of each, singling out the word "ruling", which is not a good translation of וירדו, is not a a good explanation, IMHO.

Answer (score -4):

It may seem dull because man is not the sole purpose of creation. This is the view of Maimonides, and Maimonides takes a strong stance against anthropocentrism. He writes, "Every ignoramus imagines that all that exists exists with a view to his individual sake." [1]

"'It is thought [by the ignorant] that the finality of all that exists is solely the existence of the human species so that it should worship G-d."[2]

"It should not be believed that all things exist for the sake of the existence of man. On the contrary, all other beings too have been intended for their own sakes and not for the sake of something else."[3]

Thus, G-d did not create the world only for humans, but for plants, vegetative life, animals, birds, fish, and inanimate objects.

[1] Guide, III, 12, p. 442.

[2] Ibid., III, 13, p. 451.

[3] Ibid., p. 452.

Comment: Keep reading and you'll see that this is at best misleading and at worst wrong. "G-d did not create the world only for humans" – true – "but for plants, vegetative life, animals, birds, fish, and inanimate objects" – false. G-d did not create the world for anything. G-d created the world because it was His Will to create the world. That's Maimonides' conclusion of chapter 13.

Comment: @DonielF Actually, it is impossible to know why G-d created the world. At best, it can be ascertained that it was not only for humans but for all life. Thus, do we conclude that it was His will, but G-d's will is not [and cannot], according to Maimonides, be analogous to human free will. G-d's Will is perfect and spontaneous and is not subjected to natural law, as is human will. In essence, we agree.

Comment: What I think Maimonides means to say is that G-d did not only create the world for humans, since it can be shown that other forms of life exist. G-d created the world because He wills it.

Comment: That much I agree with. But I disagree with your phrasing his opinion as “He created the world for everything else, too.” He didn’t create the world for any of us.

Comment: @DonielF I agree with you and Maimonides that G-d did not create the world for humans. Rambam's point was that if people tried to say He did, then one could point to animals. I think this was what he meant.

Comment: Maimonides writes, "It should not be believed that all things exist for the sake of the existence of man. On the contrary, all other beings too have been intended for their own sakes and not for the sake of something else."

Comment: @DonielF "G-d did not create the world for anything." That's not quite accurate. It's not particularly well known and actually represents an extreme minority opinion.

Comment: @Jonathan It may be a minority view, but it’s Rambam’s, and that’s the view we’re discussing.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: @TurkHill I stole one of your sources

Comment: @Aaron That's fine. Glad you liked the answer.

Comment: The Ramchal strongly disagrees. He writes in Derech Hashem "Of course, the main creature is truly the human specie. And all of the other creatures - whether taller than he or lower than he - are only for his sake to fulfill his function due to all of the many and different characteristics that are fitting to be found in them" - in the Ramchal's view the world was created for man and everything else are only to sustain man. He writes this explicitly in a few places

Comment: @mbloch That's an interesting view to consider. Thank you for sharing the view of the Ramchal.

Answer (score -6):

I think Maimonides answered this well. The Rambam says that the world probably wasn't created for people so people should take care of the earth and be careful not to pollute it. This interpretation suggests that animals are also important to G-d. We should show respect for animals because animals also have feelings. This is the meaning of the 7th law of Noahides.

Comment: Where does he say that?

Comment: I cannot remember the source as it has been years since last I check, but the idea is certainly there. In the intern, I will try to look for it.