# Comparing different counting of the 613 mitzvot

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah

I would like to make a rudimentary chart comparing the 613 mitzvot as enumerated by the Ramban, the Rahag, Saadia Gaon, et al. and highlighting in different colors what mitzvot are ubiquitous across the board, what mitzvos are shared by 3, by 2, and unique mitzvot.

If such a chart already exists, I would like to know where.

Comment: Hi Kfir. I'm a bit confused. In your title you ask about other lists besides the Rambam, but then you seem to know about others and just want a chart that compares them. Can you please [edit] to clarify so people can be sure to get you what you seek?

Comment: You comment is confusing. I am asking for lists of the 613 mitzvot besides the Rambam.

Comment: @KfirShlomo That comment is confusing? Now I’m confused too, more so by your clarification.

Comment: Are you asking where to find such lists? Or are you asking if there are more than Rambam/Ramban/Rahag etc. ?

Comment: it seems that you are looking for lists online of other opinions about the 613 laws so as to compare with the Rambam's list (or if there is a ready comparison). While I can find references to books online, I haven't found the other lists enumerated on a web page.

Comment: Beezras Hashem I've been working on a project like this for a while. It's a huge one and will take a long time. For now I have the Rambam and the Ramban. You can view a very early preview here: http://studioussoftware.com/613/rambam/ramban (desktop only)

Comment: robev, Toda raba! Is there an eta?

Comment: Depends on how much free time I have. Also Rambam and Ramban are easy. Bahag and rasag are not simple...also see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96596/1739 for a simple list of the differences